# Installing OpenCV on OSX 10.6 using MacPorts

Tags: c++, macos, g++, opencv

I tried installing OpenCV following the instructions for a MacPorts install on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port, typing

```
sudo port install opencv
```

in the terminal.

The install/compilation seemed to go fine, and the files are in /opt/local subdirectories as they should be. As a first test, I then tried including highgui.h in a C++ source file:

```
#include <highgui.h>
```

but when compiling with g++ or gcc, I get `error: highgui.h: No such file or directory`. I'm new to developing on a Mac, so maybe I'm missing something?
I thought I might have to set some path variable and after reading some posts I found when googling, I tried setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib, but that was wild guess and it didn't seem to help. What should I do to make the compilers find the library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacPorts installs C/C++ headers in /opt/local/include directory which is not the system default. It means that you have to explicitly tell GCC where to look for headers you are using. You can do that by specifying "-isystem" or "-I" command line options:

> -isystem dir
>              Search dir for header files, after all directories specified
>   by -I but before the standard system
>   directories.  Mark it as a system
>              directory, so that it gets the same special treatment as is
>   applied to the standard system
>   directories.  If dir begins with "=",
>   then
>              the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and
>   -isysroot.

---

> -Idir
>              Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to
>   be searched for header files.  This
>   can be used to override a system
>              header file, substituting your own version, since these
>   directories are searched before the
>   system header file directories. 
>   However,
>              you should not use this option to add directories that contain
>   vendor-supplied system header files
>   (use -isystem for that).  If you
>              use more than one -I option, the directories are scanned in
>   left-to-right order; the standard
>   system directories come after.
>
> If a standard system include directory, or a directory
>   specified with -isystem, is also
>   specified with -I, the -I option will
>   be
>              ignored.  The directory will still be searched but as a system
>   directory at its normal position in
>   the system include chain.  This is
>              to ensure that GCC's procedure to fix buggy system headers
>   and the ordering for the include_next
>   directive are not inadvertently
>              changed.  If you really need to change the search order for
>   system directories, use the -nostdinc
>   and/or -isystem options.

I recommend using -isystem because it disables some warnings you cannot fix without modifying the code. For example, using std::auto_ptr if you compile your code with -std=c++0x etcetera.

The same goes for libraries. You have to tell GCC where to find them using -L option.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work for quite some time either until I found that there is a pkg-config set.

All you have to do to compile without problems is this:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o helloWorld  helloWorld.cpp
```

or gcc if you are working with C instead of C++.

I hope that helps!

Comment: "pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv" has to be escaped with the special backticks but stackoverflow interprets them as code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Referenced from the OpenCV wiki page:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CompileOpenCVUsingMacOSX

Set the environment variables like this:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

and compile opencv code like this:

```
g++ -bind_at_load `pkg-config --cflags opencv` morphology.c -o morphology `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

and then run the code like this:

```
./morphology
```

Answer (score 0):

Macports install was working smoothly for me, it is worth to install tbb before installing opencv, massive speedup (and sadly it won't work the other way around).

`#include <highgui.h>` is not the c++ header.

Use `#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>` and its friends in `/opt/local/include` and avoid anything in `/opt/local/include/opencv`.